# why are infinite sets the best ways that describe the set of odd numbers?

Tags: calculus

Choose two ways that best describe the set of positive odd numbers.
C={1,3,5,7,9,11,13...}
A={1,3,5,7,9,11,13}
B={x=2n−1,n=1,2,3,...}
D={x=2n,n=1,2,3,...}

why is the answer C&B but not A&B?

Comment: Wouldn't you agree that $15$ should be a member of the set of all odd numbers?

Comment: For the same reason why infinite sets are the best way to describe *any* infinite set.

Comment: @Snaw Notice that you add "all" to the description of the set. I think that's what confused Zoro. After all, isn't $\{1,3,5,7,9,11,13\}$ a set of positive odd numbers?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a good question, even if poorly formated.

In Mathematics, when one talks about "**The** set of positive odd numbers" it means the set of **all** positive odd numbers. If it were "**A** set of positive odd numbers" then it would mean a set whose elements are positive odd numbers.